# Merging files in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to do below in AppleScript.

- Concatenate/Merge all *.xxx files found in a particular folder into one new file
- Each file contains a header. Strip header from all but 1st file before merging.
- Add a footer text to the merged file.

This sounds relatively simple in other languages but I am a beginner to applescript. Any help to find a direction would be appreciated.

TIA
AnuRV

Comment: The *how* strongly depends on the exact structure / contents of the files.

Comment: Oh yes. Say there are 5 columns and 10 rows of text. I am mainly looking at help on how to read the file, loop it to read the whole contents. And merge.

Comment: Please be more specific. Scripting / programming is a very precise business. Are we talking about CSV? What is the text encoding? UTF8, Latin or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details earlier, dint know that was important. The file seems to be a .tsv. Not sure of the text encoding. Can I find out by looking at the file. Looks like simple text with date, time, test name, pass/fail result etc columns.

Comment: Sorry, reading / writing text in AppleScript depends on the text encoding because UTF8, UTF16 and the rest is treated differently.

Comment: I see. I found that out now, it is a UTF8. Appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you are prompted to choose a base folder and a destination file name.

**Important:** Use a destination location outside the base folder to avoid the file to be included in the merging process.

I assume that your `tsv` file type is a typo and you mean `csv`.
If not, change all occurrences of `csv` in the script.

The text delimiter is `linefeed` (`0A`), if you need `return` (`0D`) change the occurrence of `linefeed` to `return`.

```
set baseFolder to choose folder
set destinationFile to choose file name with prompt "Choose destination file name" default name "merged.csv"
tell application "Finder" to set tsvFiles to (files of baseFolder whose name extension is "csv") as alias list
set text item delimiters to linefeed
try
    set fileDescriptor to open for access destinationFile with write permission
    repeat with i from 1 to (count tsvFiles)
        set theFile to item i of tsvFiles
        set theText to paragraphs of (read theFile as «class utf8»)
        if i = 1 then
            write (theText as text) to fileDescriptor as «class utf8»
        else
            write ((items 2 thru -1 of theText) as text) to fileDescriptor as «class utf8»
        end if
    end repeat
    close access fileDescriptor
on error
    try
        close destinationFile
    end try
end try
set text item delimiters to {""}
```